# Ibatis and polling database

Tags: database, apache-camel

I would like to use IBatis for polling 3 legacy databases for new rows and insert into a new database. But our customers don't allow me to insert one "status" column in three legacy databases which help me avoid consuming twice or more. So what do I have to do? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with the status column and add a foreign key pointing to the primary key of the legacy table. Create a view with both tables joined together and you will have your status column associated with the legacy table without altering it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But if I do like that, I will have to create a trigger to insert into the new table and then use Apache-Camel but I think we will make redundancy. So is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the idempotent consumer EIP to filter out duplicates
http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html

But as Joachim said, you need a new table to store the status.

You can maybe also create a SQL VIEW on the original table + status table, and let iBatis query that view.